# How do I implement corner correction in a platformer?

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, platformer

I'm writing a platformer in Unity and I'm trying to make it so that when the player jumps up to a ledge but barely misses (imagine they hit their toe on the ledge, or maybe even their foot, I'll play with the values) they are nudged up onto the ledge instead of not making the jump (as it is now in my game). There's a thread showing that Celeste does this in a few ways [here](https://twitter.com/MattThorson/status/1238338574220546049).

My player character uses a dynamic `Rigidbody2D` and I move the character by setting the velocity directly.

Comment: Presumably you've tried using shapecasts to check for a corner in your direction of movement? Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: I'm wondering about the approach. Do I need to set a target position and take control of the Y component of velocity for a bit?

Comment: That sounds like it might lead you in a useful direction. What happens when you try implementing that idea? Does it get the behaviour you want? Do you run into a particular snag anywhere? If so, tell us about that snag.

Comment: Did you find your answer? If so please share it, I am trying to do the same thing and nudge the player up when this happens